# Variable assignment that updates reference?

Tags: c#, reference, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment

I searched quite a bit but found no answer.

This is what I have:

```
Wrapper _wrap1;
Wrapper _wrap2;

public Wrapper GetWrapper(int num)
{
    Wrapper cachedWrapper = num == 1 ? _wrap1 : _wrap2;
    if(cachedWrapper == null)
    {
        cachedWrapper = new Wrapper();
    }

    return cachedWrapper;
}
```

I'm aware that '`cachedWrapper`' is a new reference, and will have no impact on either `_wrap1` or `_wrap2`.

I'm searching for an elegant way that will update those fields **without the need for an additional if-statement**.

My class has a lot more than just 2 Wrappers, and I have more types than just 'Wrapper'.

Thanks

Comment: Just initialize the fields when you declare them.

Comment: Can you wait for [C# 7](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1936/c-sharp-7-0-features/19197/ref-return-and-ref-local#t=201608112135378343854)?

Comment: If you have "a lot more" than 2 wrappers, perhaps they should be in a dictionary, rather than having one field per instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do precisely what you're asking.

But, adding to Blorgbeard's comment, you can use a dictionary:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

ConcurrentDictionary<int, Wrapper> wrapperDictionary;

public Wrapper GetWrapper(int num)
{
    return wrapperDictionary.GetOrAdd(num, _ => new Wrapper());
}
```